# How to construct Parse Objects from JSONs?

Tags: parse-server, parse-ios-sdk

I have JSONs like this;

```
{
    createdAt: a_date,
    text: "some text",
    likes: 8
}
```

And I want to convert them into `PFObject`s… here’s how I do it;

```
let post = PFObject(className: "Post", dictionary: jsonPost)
```

The thing is that after that, the `PFObject` doesn’t have a value at its `createdAt` property.

```
post.createdAt <== this is always nil
```

I did some digging and tried this, but still no success;

```
jsonPost["_created_at"] = ["__type": "Date", "iso": "2020-09-23T13:31:08.877Z"]
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to manually assign each param:

```
let postJson = {
    createdAt: a_date,
    text: "some text",
    likes: 8
};

// create the Parse Object with Class 'Post'
let post = Parse.Object.extend('Post');
// assign param
post.set('text', postJson.text)
post.set('likes',postJson.likes)
post.save().then()...
```

createdAt is automatically handled by Parse Server when you save an object.  If you want to manually control it with your own timestamp, then you will need to add a field:

```
post.set('myCreatedAt',postJson.createdAt)
```